# How to build multiple projects the same time using jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I already wrote an example Jenkinsfile to checkout and build and deploy a signal project. Is there a way to do all these for multiple project in different git repo the same time just using one Jenkinsfile ? I know I can set up these projects as independent jobs and use a Jenkinsfile to call them,but I'm wondering if I can do this without independent jobs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Job DSL Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/) to achieve this.

[Jenkins Job DSL API](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#) will help you to write DSL scripts. You can find all the built-in DSL methods that will be needed to construct jobs.

**Example pipeline script:**

```java
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Job1') {
            steps {
      
    //Pipeline Job

                jobDsl scriptText: '''pipelineJob(\"$job1\") {
                            definition {
          cpsScm {
          
              scm {
              git {
                remote{
                  name('origin')
                  url('https://github.com/satta19/user-node.git')
                  credentials('git2-cred')
                }
                branch ('master')
              }
            }
            scriptPath('Jenkinsfile')
          }
                  
              }
                }'''
            
            }
        }
        
        stage('Job2') {
            steps {
   
   //Freestyle job

                jobDsl scriptText: '''job(\"$job2\") {
                            steps {
                                shell(\'echo Hello World!\')
                    }
                }'''
            
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

> **Note:** I have taken the jobs name as string parameter i.e. `$job1` and `$job2` in the above example pipeline script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but it looks like job1 and job2 aren't parallel.

Comment: You need to modify the question. In question it is not mentioned to run the jobs parallel. However, it can be achieved in declarative pipeline script. Here for more details https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel